# What advantage does Tangaroa offer over PBFT?

Tags: distributed-systems, communication-protocols, consensus

Tangaroa is a relatively new project adding Byzantine fault-tolerance to the Raft consensus protocol using techniques that were already used in the PBFT algorithm. What are the advantages, when should I use Tangaroa and when PBFT?

Answer (score 1):

The notion of perfection in consensus:

Tangaroa is a BFT flavored Raft usually consisting of 3 - 5 systems in a cluster and can tolerate failure of up to 1/2 of the node count with a concept of *"randomization in election of leadership".*

PBFT is the "practical" BFT system designed for more deterministic behavior with a concept of *"eventual leadership"*.
However, I came across this research (https://www.zurich.ibm.com/~cca/papers/sieve.pdf) mentioning *"Fault-tolerant execution on multi-core servers poses a new challenge, even for deterministic applications,
because thread-level parallelism may introduce unpredictable differences between processes."* in Related Work.

Choosing which one?
I'd leave that to you once you'll be able to determine the nature of the state machine you'd like to see operational.

Hope this helps :)
Comments and corrections,(if any) are most welcome!